# Best way to scale a service that fetches data and has a REST API to query it

Tags: architecture, microservices, architectural-patterns

I have been developing a service that fetches data and also has a REST API to query the fetched data.

The problem I have is, when this service starts it is starting the data fetching process, and this is a problem when it comes to scaling, as soon as I spawn 2 instances of this service they are both fetching data.

I don't want both of them to fetch the same data, because it is the same data. I want that as soon as I scale the service, then the next instances of the service will be READ-ONLY where it doesn't fetch, but still exposes the API to query the data.

I thought about a solution but I am not sure it is the best one:

Since the service is feeding the data to a database, I can just have another collection that stores data about who is the primary service (the one that fetches the data) and who are the secondaries (only for API).

What do you guys think would be a good solution for the problem ?

If that helps : the service is written in `Node.js`

Comment: This problem outset is so dramatically underanalyzed that this can only be solved playing 20 questions (or significantly more than 20 questions). This is not realistically achievable using StackExchange's Q&A format. What you need is a proper analysis of your requirements and the architecture needed to provide those requirements.

Comment: There's a reasonably good overview of issues in this area on (sorry) Medium: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-a-cache-stampede-caused-one-of-facebooks-biggest-outages-dbb964ffc8ed

Answer (score 1):

The initial problem you have identified is the retrieval of all the data by each service. You are trying to solve that problem. However, have you thought of removing that problem or identifying the root cause of the problem. What do I mean by that?

Lets' rephrase the problem not to one of retrieving all the data but to one of retrieving only the required data needed to generate a satisfactory response to an API call. This way you can have as many services running at the same time; they just selectively pick out only the data they need, and they do so only on a request, and perhaps they even store it in cache over time for future calls (depending on the nature of the data) gradually building up the big picture you're trying to bulk load.

Now, you might reply, that's not possible with the format the data is in; and that identifies the root of the problem. Perhaps the problem you are actually facing is the data is stored in a manner that is making you retrieve it all in bulk.

Hope that helps. Cannot offer you more than that without additional information.